# How does Phylactery of Change interact with other polymorph effects on the wearer?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, polymorph

The *phylactery of change* from the *Arms and Equipment Guide* reads as follows:

> The wearer of this item can invoke a *polymorph self* ability with an indefinite duration (or until the phylactery is removed, destroyed, or dispelled). A new form can be adopted once per day. The wearer can assume his natural form without limitation, however.

How does that last rule affect a wearer suffering from a polymorph effect outside of that granted by the *phylactery* itself? Since the item can only grant a new form once per day, it seems like this item effectively grants shapeshifter-like resistance to unwanted polymorph effects. Am I reading this correctly?

(While the *Arms and Equipment Guide* is for [dnd-3e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3e), the *phylactery* was never updated to [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e) making it legal for using in a game with minor adjustments by the DM; it's in such a game that I plan to use the *phylactery*.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes...

The character effectively gets the [shapechanger](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#shapechanger) subtype's ability to resume it's natural form after a polymorph effect, but without the actual subtype.

However, there are effects that either remove equipment, such as how [*baleful polymorph*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#baleful-polymorph) does, or makes unusable equipment meld into the new form. In these cases, the Phylactery, being either not present or non functional, can't allow the user to resume it's natural form.

Comment: Note that this was far less exciting in original 3.0, because Polymorph Self acted like Shapechange in that you could change freely throughout the duration.

Comment: @fectin Normally, I wouldn't OMG, but, OMG! I had to look that up, and there it is, clear as day: *The character can change form as often as desired for the duration of the spell simply by willing it so. Each change is a full-round action.* When we started playing *3e* I switched to barbarian from wizard, having played a *2e* wizard for a decade (from level 5 all the way to level 9! Yeah!) so never saw that in play. Thank you for the reminder. I'm gonna go punch a wall.

Comment: It was fixed in Tome & Blood, but yeah. Raw 3.0 Polymorph Self was mind-bogglingly good.

Comment: Does the item's description of its power to allow the user to return to natural form at any time not supersede the school of polymorph disabling the item?

Comment: @WannabeWarlock Nope: "...The *wearer* can..." This is part of the effect of the item; no item, no effect. Unless you want it to be a permanent effect, irrespective of the item's effectiveness.

Comment: @Chemus So does the item even work in 3.5 then with the polymorph sub-group? It casts Polymorph Self, which was replaced with Polymorph, which would then absorb your gear similarly, right?

Comment: @WannabeWarlock So you'd better not change into anything that can't wear a phylactery (needs a head.) (see [*alter self*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#alter-self), which is the basis for [*polymorph*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#polymorph))